# Как получить prototype у смовызывающиеся функции JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, marionette.js

В файле лежит код такого вида (код в файле менять не могу):

```
(function (root, factory) {
    factory(root.jQuery);
}(this, function ($) {

  var Typeahead = function (element, options) {
    this.select = this.options.select || this.select;
  };

  Typeahead.prototype = {
    constructor: Typeahead,
    select: function () {
       console.log(1) 
    }
  }
}))
```

Как получить prototype самовызывающейся функции и в последующем его перезаписать, не изменяя изначальный вид.

Comment: Я не могу присвоить данную функцию переменной

Comment: если ты хочешь получить Typeahead, то не меняя приведенного кода - никак